# jquery php mysql and json returning looped data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I havent tried this before and my solution hasnt worked.

In mysql I would be able to write it using a while loop but im trying to pull the data through ajax.

Can someone help

```
var qString = 'country=' +country+'&continent='+continent;

$.post('/assets/inc/get-country.php', qString, function (data) {    
    $('#'+continent).append('<li>'+data[0].country+' '+data[0].company+'</li>');
}, "json");
```

The above returns in console.log's ajax response the following

```
[{
    "continent": "Europe",
    "country": "Spain",
    "company": "Universidade de Vigo CITI",
    "comments": "We are very satisfied with the disrupter. It's equipment is very easy to use and effective in breaking cells. I also would like to thank Constant System for for the assistance provided."
}, {
    "continent": "Europe",
    "country": "Spain",
    "company": "IPLA",
    "comments": "The Constant Systems cell disruptor has made extraction of membrane proteins from Gram positives a reproducible and efficient task in our lab."
}]
```

How can I get this to display as an li list on my page?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

```
$("#comments-tabs div.country a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var continent = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var country = $(this).attr("name");
    console.log(continent+country);
var qString = 'country=' +country+'&continent='+continent;
    $.post('/assets/inc/get-country.php', qString, function (data) {    
        for(company_nr in data){
            $('#'+continent).append('<li>'+data[company_nr].country+' '+data[company_nr].company+'</li>')
        }
    }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop it in javascript:

```
function (data)
{
   for(company_nr in data)
   {
      $('#'+continent).append('<li>'+data[company_nr].country+' '+data[company_nr].company+'</li>')
   }
}
```